# Бессубъектный деепричастный оборот

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Литература пестрит конструкциями типа:

> Возвращаясь все к той же призрачности страны… Можете представить себе
> пустой город посреди пустыни, без единого огонька?

> ― Возвращаясь к операции «Оборотень»: что больше всего поразило вас во
> время ее проведения?

> ― Возвращаясь собственно к поэзии, на Ваш взгляд, возможно появление
> твёрдой формы, специфической для русской поэзии?

Но в учебниках я что-то не встречал разрешения бессубъектных деепричастных оборотов.
Подойдут любые ссылки где рассматривается допустимость данной конструкции. Может у Розенталя что-то есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это деепричастные обороты с глаголами речи. Выполняют функцию вводных сочетаний, поэтому не соответствуют субъекту предложения.

О них есть статья [Т. В. Шмелевой "Деепричастия на службе модуса"](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:l6xVk2LrcqUJ:rusgram.ru/sites/default/files/liter/converb/shmeleva_converb.doc&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ro), 1984.

Кратко - [Русская корпусная грамматика, 6.3 Деепричастие как вводное слово](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#63).

Comment: Странно, что в полном справочнике вводных слов и выражений Фрамполь нету таких сочетаний.

Comment: Будет странно, когда найдется словарь, учитывающий все варианты заглавной темы. Это достижимо только для мертвых языков. Нет в словаре - ищи в учебнике/статье, обычное дело.

Comment: @user190920 Потому что оно не вводное, просто разговорный оборот.

Comment: См научную статью. Там позиционируется как вводное (метатекст). Но я согласен, что это несколько необычные вводные, как класс. И поэтому могли бы вставить их в справочник (они достаточно распространены)

Comment: @user190920 Там к инфинитиву относится (*высказать, возвращаясь*). И интонация другая. А в другой статье указан правильный вариант: *Если возвращаться к проблеме нормы, то следует отметить...*

Answer (score 4):

**Не очень-то новые статьи**,  1984 год… Да и вводные слова на основе деепричастий ― это вещь давно известная.
А вот  приведенные в вопросе конструкции больше напоминают **этакую изящную журналистскую небрежность в стиле интервью**.

Ведь деепричастная конструкция с предложением вовсе никак не связана. Фраза,  прерванная на полуслове ― вот на что похож этот **деепричастный модус**. Стиль совершенно новый, но уже, видно, в ходу.

Ну мне так показалось, извините...

Comment: В английском есть похожий оборот, употребляющийся как раз в журналистских заметках. Но видимо там настоящий оборот, а не только состоящий из метафраз (ведь вводные слова там тоже есть).